# I cannot see my details in the dba.stackexchange site also unable to post. Other stacks are fine

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I'm not seeing my username at the top of the website and cannot post

Comment: Could you have logged out accidentally? If so, just try logging back in. Although that would still not explain why you were unable to post.

Comment: You might need to post a screenshot of what the site's top part looks like for you in case logging in doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your account. Can you explain what happened between [your last comment](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47045/workaround-for-using-functions-in-restricted-system#comment84620_47045) and this post?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache?

Comment: It's working now, I didn't make any changes other than rebooting

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: meta.SO has a "non-repro" close reason for this type of thing. Might be a good idea to add it here too (though the level of traffic might not justify it).

Comment: @Mat it'd be useful, but I'd have to ask for that (I can add/edit off-topic reasons but this doesn't seem to fit under off-topic and I hate to overload that even more. And I think you're right, volume is unlikely to justify another person's effort, even if minor.

Comment: I was having problems last night (the CDN was timing out), but it fixed itself in about 10 minutes. I suspect you had old CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this was a transient issue that no longer reproduces.